# django.apps: an error appears during the template rendering when I loop on get_models()

Tags: python, django

I want to display the list of applications and the models of these applications in an HTML page.

In view.py I update my view context with this :

```
from django.apps import apps
context.update({applications: apps.get_app_configs()})
```

in my template, when I loop on application, it works:

```
{% for application in applications %}
    {{ application }}
{% endfor %}
```

But when I loop on the models, it doesn't work anymore:

```
{% for application in applications %}
    {{ application }}
    {% for model in application.get_models %}
        {{ model }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I get:

> RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /dumpy/
>   Permission has no content_type.

The strange thing is that in a shell, this works fine:

```
from django.apps import apps
for application in apps.get_app_configs():
    print (application)
    for model in application.get_models():
        print(model)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the console uses the model class, whereas template rendering will instantiate a class first, then try to print it. So basically it's printing a `Permission()` instance, not the `Permission` class.

You could create a template filter (*my_filters.py*) to do it:

```
@register.filter()
def class_repr(obj):
    return repr(obj.__class__)
```

And then in your template:

```
{% load my_filters %}
...
{{ model|class_repr }}
```